# how do I format my SSD plugged in as external

Tags: ssd, format

I have an SSD plugged in as an external drive through some sort of an adapter, what I'm wondering is how do I format that drive when I'm running a HDD right now? Do I just right click on the drive and format? I'm running Windows 8.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the drive is recognized by Windows, you can simply format it as you described or through Disk Management.

Comment: That's the problem, many external SSD drives aren't recognized by windows when plugged in through USB.

Answer (score 0):

A SSD you have to align. I have made **[this little tutorial](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/113967-ssd-alignment.html?ltr=S)** that will show you how to do it.